# Rails3 filter is being skipped in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a strange behavior of Rails 3.0.10. Got this application controller:

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
require 'api/api_controller'

# rest not important
```

app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb

```
class Api::ApiController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :require_user

  def require_user
    @user = User.find(xxx, yyy)
  end
end
```

and then this controller:

app/controllers/api/ac_controller.rb

```
class Api::AcController < Api::ApiController

  before_filter :find_pool, :only => [:add_pool, :remove_pool]

  def add_pool
    # some logic that needs @user to be set
  end

  def remove_pool
    # some logic that needs @user to be set
  end

  def find_pool
    # some logic here
  end

end
```

My problem is when I run this in **production** mode the require_user filter is NOT called. When I try this in the **development** mode, it works.

Now, I understand in development mode classes are being reloaded, but the question is why the require_user filter does NOT get called?

Edit: Please note AC controller is before API controller lexicographically.

Comment: The first one does not look like an application controller, at least the second one does not inherit from it.

Comment: Michal - yeah sorry, I fixed it - bad copy&paste

Comment: According to this, it should be called, but it is not: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like order of required files problem or the `ApiController` being loaded twice. Once before `AcController` and one more time after `AcController` being loaded. This could cause, that `find_pool` filter will get evaluated before `require_user`. `ApiController` is alse after `AcController` in lex order.

The problem might be caused by `require "api_controller"` being present somewhere - it should be handled by Rails and does not need to be put down explicitly. So if there is such a line, removing it could help.

Comment: Removed the require statement, ty

Answer (score 1):

Typically the  methods called by filters should NOT be public. Public methods in controllers are treated as actions. Have you tried making `require_user` a `private` method?